# Sequence contains more than one element error in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

[image]

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the procedure is returning more than one record.

You should use `First` instead of `Single` if you expecting multiple records.

```
Database.SqlQuery<int>("exec GetMaxInvoiceNumber @centerId",sqlCenterId).First();
```

Or you should modify your procedure as returning single record.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CenterInvoiceNumberMaxes WHERE CenterID = @centerID)
BEGIN
    -- Get next invoice number
    UPDATE CenterInvoiceNumberMaxes SET MaxInvoiceNumber = MaxInvoiceNumber + 1 WHERE CenterID = @centerID
    select max(MaxInvoiceNumber) from CenterInvoiceNumberMaxes WHERE CenterID = @centerID
END
```

Comment: when i replace single to first the an error  Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: foreach (var entryDeleted in deleteEntities)
            {
                var entityKeyObject = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entryDeleted.Entity).EntityKey;
                var entityKey = entityKeyObject.EntityKeyValues.Length >= 1 ? entityKeyObject.EntityKeyValues[0].Value : 0;
                var entityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entryDeleted.Entity.GetType()).Name;